# Overriding native methods and objects INSIDE a particular object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to override a native method called "localStorage" for functions INSIDE an object.

Here's a gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
function SomeObject(){
   this.localStorage = "aaa"; //block access to localStorage for functions INSIDE this object.
      ... (some more code here)
   _testRun(){
      window.testA = localStorage; //chose to store the instance on a window (global-like) object
   }
   this.testRun = function(){ _testRun(); };
   this.testRun2 = function(){ window.testB = localStorage;};v
}
var a = new SomeObject();
a.testRun();
a.testRun2();

(after this, when I look up window.testA and window.testB, they both point to the Native localStorage, not the custom one inside the SomeObject.)
```

BTW, I don't want to override a native function for the whole document.
(i.e. might use native localStorage OUTSIDE the object)

Any suggestions/solutions on how I can do this? thanks!

Comment: Try window.testB = this.localStorage, it should related to scope variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `window.localStorage` and `this.localStorage` instead of just `localStorage`

```
function SomeObject(){
   this.localStorage = "aaa"; //block access to localStorage for functions INSIDE this object.
      ... (some more code here)
   _testRun(){
      window.testA = window.localStorage; //chose to store the instance on a window (global-like) object
   }
   this.testRun = function(){ _testRun(); };
   this.testRun2 = function(){ window.testB = this.localStorage;};
}
```

Comment: sorry Derek, but this isn't what I'm looking for...I'm kind of trying to "shadow" a global variable for functions INSIDE a particular object